# Wix installer: The application is launched in SYSTEM user

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6

I have an installer in WIX. I have tried to deploy it to a group of target computers in the network and encountered the following issue. The deployment was successful but there is an issue when the installer launches the application after the installation finishes using the following code:

```
    <CustomAction Id="RunMainApp" Directory="SUBDIR" ExeCommand="[SUBDIR]clicksharelauncher.exe" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunMainApp" Before="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[UILevel=5 OR LAUNCH_APP~="YES" AND NOT Installed]]></Custom> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When the application is launched, I realized that it is launched in SYSTEM user. Therefore, I get an error from the application saying that the application can't run in SYSTEM user. Could anyone tell me if there is a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the InstallExecute phase of the installation runs as the SYSTEM account, and you're launching the application during that phase.

You'll need to get the custom action to Impersonate the user executing the installation by adding Impersonate="yes" to the custom action element.

More details can be found under the Impersonate section here:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html

The following link provides details on how to add the startup of an application in the UI:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

Comment: This may not help.  If he's "deploying to a group of computers on a network" (think SCCM)  he may likely be invoking the installer as SYSTEM and so it wouldn't matter which sequence, phase or impersonation context he uses as it would all be SYSTEM.  I'd want to know why he's calling an EXE... what it does.  The right answer is likely to not call the EXE.

Comment: Hi. Actually I coded everything as if user is installing the application from his own account. Therefore, I have no such issue. The idea is that the application should be launched after the installation.
We went one step further and tried to deploy it to a group of computers and encountered such a problem. So, I will add impersonate since it should be there as default implementation. However, I would like to ask you how I can detect this issue during installation and not launch the application when installation finishes. Thanks.

Comment: Good point Christopher - my answer would assume that it was a real user account running the installation.

Comment: How can I check if it is a real user account?

Comment: No way of detecting it?

Comment: You could look at the USERNAME attribute, but knowing that might not help. Another issue is privilege. An impersonated CA will not run elevated by default, so if the user is admin and expecting an elevated app there could be an issue. Bottom line is that it can often not be useful to run a user app from the context of an install. That's what shortcuts are for :)